# Error while filling the ProtoInfo in Bazel rule - "Provider" object is not callable

Tags: protocol-buffers, bazel, bazel-rules

I am trying to populate ProtoInfo structure in Bazel rule.
Code:

```
load("@rules_proto//proto:defs.bzl", "ProtoInfo")
 
def _impl(ctx):
    # Other code that generates .proto file
    # ...

    return [ProtoInfo(
        direct_sources = [proto_file.path]
    )
 
my_rule = rule(
    attrs = {
        "spec": attr.label(
            mandatory = True,
            allow_single_file = [
                ".json",
                ".yaml",
                ".yml",
            ],
        ),    
    },
    implementation = _impl,
    provides = [ProtoInfo],
)
```

For some reason an error is returned:

> "Provider" object is not callable.

I want to populate ProtoInfo because the .proto file is automatically generated using an internal tool and I want to pass it to cc_proto_library as a dependency.

Any idea what's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0):

This area has undergone significant churn between Bazel 6.x and what will be Bazel 7 as the builtin proto rules were rewritten in Starlark. Constructing `ProtoInfo` will work with Bazel@HEAD. For 6.x, `proto_common.ProtoInfo` should do the job.